# Not able to change the value of variable after going through the function which changes the value in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-hooks, jsx

I am trying to change the `filterName` value on onclick of the filter button, but while being inside the `showFilter function`, the value is changing but when I `console.log()` it outside the `showFilter function` then it did not have any value its showing that the variable is empty, like how it was before getting into the function, please help me out

main code (`showFilter function`  and variable thats not changing) is just in `Filter.js` but i am giving all files connected to it by chance if you need them for solving the problem thanks please help me out.

This is Filter.js

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import { FilterBtn } from './FilterBtn'
import { FilterOpt } from './FilterOpt';
import { Items } from './SortItem';

export const Filter = () => {
  const filterNames = ['Color', 'Price', 'Brand', 'All Filters'];
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const [position, setPosition] = useState('');

  //main function starts here taht would change the value
  let filterName; // the variable which needs to be changed.
  const showFilter = (text) => { // text is the paramenter i am taking from FilterBtn
    if (show === true) {
      setShow(false);
    } else {
      if (text === 'Color') {      // it should change the value from these conditions but its not changing                               
        setPosition('5%');
        filterName = 'color';
      } else if (text === 'Price') {
        setPosition('11.2%');
        filterName = 'price';
      } else if (text === 'Brand') {
        setPosition('17.4%');
        filterName = 'brand';
      } else if (text === 'All Filters') {
        setPosition('24%');
        filterName = 'All Filters';
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(filterName) // filterName needed to have value but it's empty and shows undefined in console.


  useEffect(() => {
    if (document.getElementById('FilterOpt')) {
      document.getElementById('FilterOpt').style.left = position;
    }
  }, [position])

  let itemData = [];
  Items.map((i) => {
    for (const key in i) {
      if (i.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        itemData.push(`${key}: ${i[key]}`);
      }
    }
  })
  let itemUniqueData = [...new Set(itemData)]
  return (
    <div className="filter_main">
      <div className="left_filter">
        {filterNames.map((filter, index) => {
          return (
            <React.Fragment key={index}>
              // calling the showFilter function here on this BTN
              <FilterBtn text={filter} showFilter={showFilter} />
            </React.Fragment>)
        })}
        {show && (<div id="FilterOpt">
          {itemUniqueData.map((i, index) => {
            if (filterName === 'color') {
              if (itemUniqueData[index].match(filterName)) {
                return (
                  <FilterOpt text={itemUniqueData[index].slice(itemUniqueData[index].indexOf(':') + 2).toUpperCase()} key={index} />
                )
              }
            } else if (filterName === 'price') {
              if (itemUniqueData[index].match(filterName)) {
                return (
                  <FilterOpt text={itemUniqueData[index].slice(itemUniqueData[index].indexOf(':') + 2).toUpperCase()} key={index} />
                )
              }
            } else if (filterName === 'brand') {
              if (itemUniqueData[index].match(filterName)) {
                return (
                  <FilterOpt text={itemUniqueData[index].slice(itemUniqueData[index].indexOf(':') + 2).toUpperCase()} key={index} />
                )
              }
            }
          })}
        </div>)}
      </div>
      <div className="right_filter">
        <button className="filter_btn">Sort By<i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

this is FilterOpt.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const FilterOpt = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <button>{text}</button>
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

this is FilterBtn.js

```
import React from 'react'

export const FilterBtn = ({ text, showFilter }) => {
  return (
    <button className="filter_btn" onClick={() => { showFilter(text) }}> {text} <i className="fa fa-angle-down"></i></button>
  )
}
```

this is SortItem.js

```
export const Items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    image: './images/Items/wireless_earbuds.jpg',
    name: 'Wireless Earbuds, IPX8',
    price: 89,
    info: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    rating: 4.6,
    review: 78,
    type: 'true wireless',
    color: 'black',
    brand: 'IPX8',
    discount: '20',
    microphonepresent: 'yesyes',
    offers: 'buy more save more',
    compaitaiblewith: 'all',
    category: 'audio & video'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    image: './images/Items/airpods_pink.jpg',
    name: 'AirPods Max',
    price: 559,
    info: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    rating: 5,
    review: 121,
    type: 'true wireless',
    color: 'pink',
    brand: 'IPX8',
    discount: '',
    microphonepresent: 'yes',
    offers: 'no cost EMI',
    compaitaiblewith: 'laptop mobile desktop',
    category: 'audio & video'
  }, {
    id: 3,
    image: './images/Items/bose.webp',
    name: 'Bose BT Earphones',
    price: 289,
    info: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    rating: 4.2,
    review: 88,
    type: 'wired & wireless',
    color: 'black',
    brand: 'IPX8',
    discount: '25',
    microphonepresent: 'yes',
    offers: 'speical price',
    compaitaiblewith: '',
    category: 'audio & video'
  }, {
    id: 4,
    image: './images/Items/vivefox.webp',
    name: 'VEVEFOX Headphones',
    price: 39,
    info: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    rating: 4.3,
    review: 90,
    type: 'wired & wireless',
    color: 'red',
    brand: 'IPX8',
    discount: '',
    microphonepresent: 'yes',
    offers: 'no cost EMI',
    compaitaiblewith: 'audio player',
    category: 'audio & video'
  }, {
    id: 5,
    image: './images/Items/jbl.webp',
    name: 'JBL TUNE 60CB TNC',
    price: 59,
    info: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.',
    rating: 3.7,
    review: 34,
    type: 'wireless',
    color: 'black',
    brand: 'IPX8',
    discount: '30',
    microphonepresent: 'yes',
    offers: 'buy more save more',
    compaitaiblewith: 'desktop',
    category: 'audio & video'
  }
]
```

Comment: That function will only be called when something is clicked. Your code attempts to access the value immediately after simply *defining* the function. At that point, it will of course not have been called.

Comment: brother I am clicking the button but still its not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `useState` to declare the `filterName` variable like this

```js
const [ filterName, setFilterName ] = useState('');
```

instead of declaring it with a let keyword.
it should work fine now.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `filterName` variable is declared outside the scope of the `showFilter` function and is not being preserved in the state. In React, to preserve the state of a variable, you need to use `useState` hook.
Every time when you do something that makes component to rerender `filterName` variable is initializing again with `undefined` value.
You need to do something like that

```js
const [filterName, setFilterName] = useState(''); 
const showFilter = (text) => {
    if (show === true) {
      setShow(false);
    } else {
      if (text === 'Color') {
        setPosition('5%');
        setFilterName('color'); // Updating filterName using setFilterName
      } else if (text === 'Price') {
        setPosition('11.2%');
        setFilterName('price'); // Updating filterName using setFilterName
      } else if (text === 'Brand') {
        setPosition('17.4%');
        setFilterName('brand'); // Updating filterName using setFilterName
      } else if (text === 'All Filters') {
        setPosition('24%');
        setFilterName('All Filters'); // Updating filterName using setFilterName
      }
    }
  }
```

Or you can store it in `ref`:

```js
const filterNameRef = useRef(''); 
const showFilter = (text) => {
    if (show === true) {
      setShow(false);
    } else {
      if (text === 'Color') {
        setPosition('5%');
        filterNameRef.current = 'color';
      } else if (text === 'Price') {
        setPosition('11.2%');
        filterNameRef.current = 'price';
     } else if (text === 'Brand') {
        setPosition('17.4%');
         filterNameRef.current = 'brand';
      } else if (text === 'All Filters') {
        setPosition('24%');
        filterNameRef.current = 'All Filters'; 
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks Brother your way worked for me , there is one more issue if you don't mind, in the same code, in FilterOpt div it's not rendering or writing anything in the console or anywhere please help me brother once more